# Find joins in metadata for 2 specific columns

Tags: python, metadata

I want to use the metadata from a relational database to find all possible joins.

| OWNER | TABLE | COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 1 | COLUMN 1 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 1 | COLUMN 2 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 1 | COLUMN 3 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 2 | COLUMN 1 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 2 | COLUMN 2 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 2 | COLUMN 3 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 3 | COLUMN 1 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 3 | COLUMN 2 |
| OWNER 1 | TABLE 3 | COLUMN 3 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 1 | COLUMN 1 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 1 | COLUMN 2 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 1 | COLUMN 3 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 2 | COLUMN 1 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 2 | COLUMN 2 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 2 | COLUMN 3 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 3 | COLUMN 1 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 3 | COLUMN 2 |
| OWNER 2 | TABLE 3 | COLUMN 3 |

E.g.:
OWNER 1 -> TABLE 2 -> COLUMN 3
is an attribute which I want to connect with another attribute
OWNER 1 -> TABLE 3 -> COLUMN 2

Both attributes are linked through different keys / id's (possible in multiple tables / columns).

Can somebody give me any advice?

I tried a recursion but it failed